# multi line in grid @ windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, grid

hey,
i am stuck in a problem since few days and i hope some1 could help me.
i got somes values in IO in second page and i would like when the user press a button in the first page to put them in some TB in a grid. and add a new row in a grid
something like

foreach product
product ++
new row ++

etc
but i dont know how to add row in a grid via csharp side

ty

Comment: why do you need to add a row to a grid? why not just use a listbox or stackpanel? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest binding your listbox on page to an ObservableCollection of your objects.

When you add rows to this ObservableCollection, your listbox will then automatically update.

Comment: is it possible to make a mutli item listbox ?

Comment: The listbox will perform well accomodating a large number of items and display any attributes you choose to show within performance constraints. This is a simple demo project demonastrating what can be done using Data Templates, which can be made much more sophisticated. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72

Comment: i m doing this. a listbox in a observable collection serialized with json. now i m trying to find how binding 5 items to 5 textblock

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with something like this:

```
ContentPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition{Height = new GridLength(50)});

var newRowIndex = ContentPanel.RowDefinitions.Count - 1;

var newTb = new TextBlock{Text = "new"};

Grid.SetRow(newTb, newRowIndex);

ContentPanel.Children.Add(newTb);
```

**BUT**
there's probably a better way to do what you're trying to achieve. If you can tell us more about what you're trying to achieve and why you're trying to do it this way we may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: well i got a listbox with product in page 1. when the user click on a item, page2 pop where he can see the list of details of the product. if he double tap one of the detail, he go on page 3 where he can edit the item or add another one. then i save the data in IS and after that i would like to create another row in order to avoid overwriting on page2.

Comment: @user569574 I still don't understand why you have to use a grid but hope the code helps.

Comment: well here is the iphone version of what i want to do  http://hpics.li/8b50d72  . i need when i press the + button adding new row in a grid or in another container ty for ur help

Comment: @user569574 that doesn't have to be a grid though. It could be a multi-templated listbox or stackpanel.